# how change mysqli_connect to mysql_connect and mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, mysqli

**i have this connection**

```
    <?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = 'databasename';
    $conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    ?>
```

**but my old connection dosen't work with this code**

```
        //connect to database
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($link,'databasename');
//get all rows
$query = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM categories');
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
    $menu_array[$row['catid']] = array('catname' => $row['catname'],'parentid' => $row['parentid']);
    $menu_array[$row['catid']] = array('catname' => $row['catname'],'parentid' => $row['parentid'],'catid'=>$row['catid']);
}
//recursive function that prints categories as a nested html unorderd list
function generate_menu($parent)
{
$has_childs = false;
//this prevents printing 'ul' if we don't have subcategories for this category
global $menu_array;
    //use global array variable instead of a local variable to lower stack memory requierment
    foreach($menu_array as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value['parentid'] == $parent)
        {
            //if this is the first child print '<ul>'
            if ($has_childs === false)
            {
                //don't print '<ul>' multiple times
                $has_childs = true;
                echo '<ul>';
            }
            echo '<li><a href="category.php?catid='. $value['catid'] . '">' . $value['catname'] . '</a>';
```

**I think My erro located between this code .. Finally i need just replace mysqli_connect to mysql_connect Without I**

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
    $menu_array[$row['catid']] = array('catname' => $row['catname'],'parentid' => $row['parentid']);
}
```

Comment: try adding mysql drivers to your database settings

Comment: What does "**but my old connection dosen't work with this code**" mean exactly?

Comment: mysql_* is **deprecated**. Replacing new code with old code is rarely wise.

Comment: You really should leave it as `mysqli` and get it working that way. `mysql_query` is a dusty artifact from the 1990s that is not supposed to be used in new applications.

Comment: @MikeBrant if use mysql without i - sql say mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in and  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in foreach($menu_array as $key => $value) i think with mysq can't use this =>

Comment: @deceze i have this connection   `$conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    ?>` this is original but second code have this connection  
 `$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($link,'databasename');`
i need to work with my friest connection $conn with second code but it doesn't work  !! :S

Comment: And what does that mean, "need to work with first connection"?! You cannot mix mysql_ and mysqli_ functions, if that's what you mean. You simply cannot.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using mysqli_connect and mysqli_select_db.

Also change `$query = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM categories');` to be:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM `categories`');
```

I think the problem could be the connection, everything else looks fine, I dont think you can access a mysqli object with normal mysql_conn..

Give it a shot

**Also, don't change to mysql, it is far too old now! Look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and the [php data object](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) both are very well documented**